# ConstraintLayout children not properly aligned in parent view

Tags: java, android

I am trying to have two text boxes in a parent view, one on the left with static text and the other containing information. I wanted the information text to take as much space as it needed horizontally but not overlap with the title which should be possible with a ConstraintLayout. The title is showing up properly but I have not been able to align the information text box to the right of the screen, not sure what the issue is. I am using ConstraintLayout 1.0.2 which I think is the latest version.

Here is the xml file for the ConstraintLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/information"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/error_layout"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|end"
        android:text="@string/error_layout"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:background="@color/accent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the class that I use to create new views.

```
public class InformationView extends RelativeLayout {
    public InformationView(Context context, String title, String summary, int color) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_information, null);
        addView(view);

        setBackgroundColor(color);

        TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView summaryView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.summary);

        titleView.setText(title);
        summaryView.setText(summary);
    }
}
```

Here is where I add the views.

```
    LinearLayout information = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.information);
    InformationView packageView = new InformationView(context, getString(R.string.package_layout), appInfo.getAPK(), getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
    InformationView versionView = new InformationView(context, getString(R.string.version_layout), appInfo.getVersion(), getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_dark));
    InformationView appSizeView = new InformationView(context, getString(R.string.size_layout), getString(R.string.development_layout), getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
    InformationView cacheSizeView = new InformationView(context, getString(R.string.cache_size_layout), getString(R.string.development_layout), getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_dark));
    InformationView dataFolderView = new InformationView(context, getString(R.string.data_layout), appInfo.getData(), getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
    InformationView sourceFolderView = new InformationView(context, getString(R.string.source_layout), appInfo.getSource(), getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_dark));
    informations.addView(packageView);
    informations.addView(versionView);
    informations.addView(appSizeView);
    informations.addView(cacheSizeView);
    informations.addView(dataFolderView);
    informations.addView(sourceFolderView);
```

This is what the view looks like. The second text box seems to be aligned with the first even though it should be further to the right.

[image: alignment issue]

Answer (score 0):

In your `summary` view, change the width to `0dp` and add a `constraintLeft`. You will wind up with this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/summary"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center|end"
    android:text="@string/error_layout"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:background="@color/accent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/title"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Just tried that, now the information is [gone](http://imgur.com/a/nu90I) completely. It looks correct on the design view in android studio though.